# Bitnami Django Stack - not importing modules

Tags: django, apache2, bitnami

I just tried deploying my Django application on my windows machine using Bitnami's Django stack. However, when I try to access my project via `localhost/myapp/`, I get an error stating that I can't load my modules/python libraries. I checked via `pip` and I have these modules installed. It seems this error applies to all my modules/python libraries. How do I solve this? Thanks!

Comment: Can you add any more detail about how you went through deployment? Typically the modules are installed on the server during deployment; it'll read a config file in your app. Did that occur?

Answer (score 0):

When you install the Bitnami Django Stack, it will ask you for changing Association Setting for Python with the following message:

"This option lets you change the Windows properties to associate the Python files to the new Python that are going to be installed. If you have your own Python you may want to disable this feature."

If you decided to use your Python instead of the one that is installed with the Stack, you have must ensure that you have installed Python in your system and all the modules and libraries are loaded, otherwise you won't be able to use any of them.